# Unix - Sorting Text file content based on first two column values

Tags: sorting, unix

I am trying to sort the content of a file `t1.txt` based on the first two column values available in it. If the combination of first two column values are same then it should keep the lines as it and shouldn't consider the complete line for sorting it. Please find my findings below.

**Query Used :**

cat t1.txt | sort -nk 1,2

**File - t1.txt**

```
1993-04-11 07:25:16,668 INFO  b: [Cool: read-189231]: Setting
1993-04-11 07:25:16,668 INFO  ab: [Cool: read-189231]: Completed
1993-04-11 07:25:22,768 INFO  ba: [Cool: read-190983]: Execute
1993-04-11 07:25:22,768 INFO  a: [Cool: read-190983]: Main

1993-01-04 06:24:23,148 INFO  b: [Cool: read-189231]: Setting
1993-01-04 06:24:23,148 INFO  ab: [Cool: read-189231]: Completed
1993-01-04 06:25:22,068 INFO  ba: [Cool: read-190983]: Execute
1993-01-04 06:25:22,068 INFO  a: [Cool: read-190983]: Main
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1993-01-04 06:24:23,148 INFO  b: [Cool: read-189231]: Setting
1993-01-04 06:24:23,148 INFO  ab: [Cool: read-189231]: Completed
1993-01-04 06:25:22,068 INFO  ba: [Cool: read-190983]: Execute
1993-01-04 06:25:22,068 INFO  a: [Cool: read-190983]: Main

1993-04-11 07:25:16,668 INFO  b: [Cool: read-189231]: Setting
1993-04-11 07:25:16,668 INFO  ab: [Cool: read-189231]: Completed
1993-04-11 07:25:22,768 INFO  ba: [Cool: read-190983]: Execute
1993-04-11 07:25:22,768 INFO  a: [Cool: read-190983]: Main
```

**Actual Output:**

```
1993-01-04 06:24:23,148 INFO  ab: [Cool: read-189231]: Completed
1993-01-04 06:24:23,148 INFO  b: [Cool: read-189231]: Setting
1993-01-04 06:25:22,068 INFO  a: [Cool: read-190983]: Main
1993-01-04 06:25:22,068 INFO  ba: [Cool: read-190983]: Execute

1993-04-11 07:25:16,668 INFO  ab: [Cool: read-189231]: Completed
1993-04-11 07:25:16,668 INFO  b: [Cool: read-189231]: Setting
1993-04-11 07:25:22,768 INFO  a: [Cool: read-190983]: Main
1993-04-11 07:25:22,768 INFO  ba: [Cool: read-190983]: Execute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the `-s` option to sort, to enforce a stable sort. From https://ss64.com/bash/sort.html:

> Finally, as a last resort when all keys compare equal (or if no
>   ordering options were specified at all), 'sort' compares the entire
>   lines. The last resort comparison honors the '-r' global option. The
>   '-s' (stable) option disables this last-resort comparison so that
>   lines in which all fields compare equal are left in their original
>   relative order. If no fields or global options are specified, '-s' has
>   no effect.